# Create a new Array taking only elements that are even and bigger than 25 - JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

If someone can answer, it would be greatly appreciatted.

here is what I have so far:

```
public class Array {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int array[] ={23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};
    int array2[] = new int[array.length];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i= 0;i < array.length;i ++)
    {
      if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i] > 25) {
        array2[count] = array[i];
        count ++;
      }


    }/* Here is how I print it and it gives me the answer and the remaining 
        elements as O s.*/ 
    for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Sorry for the mistakes, they are now corrected.

Comment: what do you mean by pair

Comment: sorry I meant even

Comment: I think he means even, because he is doing %2.

Comment: Why don't you use a dynamic array like ArrayList to store the elements which are even and bigger than 25 ?

Comment: what's wrong with the code above? the only thing i'd change to "optimize" it is to check greater than 25 first before checking for even, you can do `array2[count++] = array[i];` and remove the `count++;` afterwards.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I dont know it just prints 0000

Comment: @EdenForrest the code you provided doesn't have a print anywhere... post all of your code

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

First You have to declare what `i` is. You can do this by changing

```
 for (i= 0;i < array.length;i ++)
```

into

```
 for (int i= 0;i < array.length;i ++)
```

or declaring `i`  before the loop

```
int i;
```

Coming to the question **`"Create a new Array taking only elements that are even and bigger than 25"`**

As you have Declared and initialized an array with same length as the first array so even if you don't initialize the remaining element they will have default value of Zero; to overcome this you can create a new array and pass all the non-zero element to it.

```
int[] arr3 = new int[count];
    for(int i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
         if(array2[i] != 0) arr3[i] = array2[i];
        }
```

Comment: Just loop up to `count` in the last loop. No need to compare with 0.

Comment: For convenience, use `array2 = Arrays.copyOf(array2, count);` to truncate away the trailing zeroes.